# Paypal recurring questions ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I've been following [Railscast 289](http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing) tutorial on how to make recurring payments using Paypal.

I got everything working now except that I am now struggling to figure out how am I able to know if the user cancelled their subscription in paypal.

**What I've done**

I've manage to set the IPN url in the paypal merchant account and everytime someone subscribes it will send me data from paypal to my webhook.

Now I am storing all the parameters that paypal sends me but I am unable to figure out which of the parameters I should be checking in order to know if the user has cancelled their subscription or if it had not enough funds, etc.

At least this is the way I think it works.

I'm using [Paypal Recurring Gem](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring)

**Questions**

How do I notice when an user has cancelled their subscription when paypal sends me their IPN to my webhook.

My webhook atm

```
def create
    user_id = Subscription.find_by(paypal_customer_token: params[:payer_id]).user_id
    PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, user_id: user_id, user_role_id: params[:item_number], status: params[:payment_status], transaction_id: params[:txn_id])
    @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if PaymentNotification.last.params[:profile_status] == "Cancelled"
        @user.update_attributes(user_role_id: 1)
    end
    render nothing: true
end
```

**Notice** that I don't want to update the users attribute instantly I want to wait until their month subscription has ended.

I'm currently storing their IPN call in PaymentNotification table.

```
create_table "payment_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "params"
  t.integer  "user_role_id"
  t.string   "status"
  t.string   "transaction_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

Also, what is the best way to check for these parameters in order to take action to users who haven't paid or have cancelled their subscription?

I have another table which stores the subscriptions

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_role_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "paypal_customer_token"
  t.string   "paypal_recurring_profile_token"
  t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
end
```

`user_role` being in this case the `plan` they are subscribing.

Comment: have you considered storing the subscription expiration date in your subscription table? When a notification comes in, you update that value. You'll need a daemon or chronjob to run daily/hourly/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPN ensures that you're notified when there's any change to your transactions, from a recurring payment perspective, when your customer cancels the profile, an event triggered POST-Back will be sent to your IPN listener.

A sample raw POST-Back message of profile cancelation will be like this,

```
payment_cycle=Daily &txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel &last_name=US &next_payme
nt_date=N/A &residence_country=US &initial_payment_amount=0.00 &currency_code=USD &t
ime_created=19:25:09 Sep 24, 2015 PDT &verify_sign=AgUGxKs4vGiEqeit6IyHkIjDJVpeAqCMRVC4wh9CZYotn
Jqrr-3oWsFe &period_type= Trial &payer_status=verified &test_ipn=1 &tax=0.00 &pa
yer_email=USP@email.com &first_name=Payer &receiver_email=USM@email.com &payer_id=8FMFQ2
KVYYHTY &product_type=1 &shipping=0.00 &amount_per_cycle=2.00 &profile_status=Cancel
led &charset=gb2312 &notify_version=3.8 &amount=2.00 &outstanding_balance=0.00 &recurring_payment_id=I-30FKJ55UV1RW &product_name=RP BA Test &ipn_track_id=65583f3a80f10
```

1. How would you be able to notice when a cancelation happens?

   Read the parameter `txn_type` in the IPN message, and determine event type with it (in your case, the event type would be `recurring_payment_profile_cancel`, find more details on `txn_type` list in the [PayPal IPN Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z))
2. Reconcile the profile/subscription with your database entry and take action

   Match the `recurring_payment_id=I-30FKJ55UV1RW` from the IPN message with your pre-stored database entry `paypal_recurring_profile_token`, and take action to update the `user_role_id` field. (Either stop the subscription instantly or update/set a new expiration date based on your business mode)

Comment: hey, thanks for answering. So I just need to keep an eye on the `txn_type` in order to take the correct action right?

Comment: exactly,  `txn_type` is the first thing to look at when you got a IPN message in this case